# Execute javascript before form is submitted on clicking a Paypal button

Tags: javascript, paypal

I'm trying to execute some JS right before my Paypal button is clicked, like this:

```
$('#paypal-button-container form').submit(function(){
  beforePaypalSubmit();
});
```

The contents of beforePaypalSubmit() are:

```
function beforePaypalSubmit()
{
  $.ajax({
    type:     'GET'
  , url:      urls.beforePaypalSubmit
  , data:     {
      id: state.id
    }
  , async:    true
  });
}
```

This simple ajax call should result in a database row being inserted but it isn't. I get 0 PHP error in the logs. Actually, the url doesn't even gets called (checked in the access log).
If I do a simple alert() instead of beforePaypalSubmit(), it gets called.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try putting an `onclick` event on the element that is clicked and submits the form. the code within `onclick` will be fired before submit.

Answer (score 0):

May not be related but try changing async to false if you want the script to run before the normal submit action is called.

Comment: I had actually tried that too, and have just tried it one more time to be sure, but it still doesn't get called.